# How to get R htmlWidgets to work on Windows 10 machine?

Tags: r, htmlwidgets

I am trying to work my way through an R htmlWidgets tutorial and I am occuring what seems to be a bug related to Windows 10.

The code below works on my Windows 7 machine but not my Windows 10 machine:

```
# libpath
.libPaths("C:/R/R-3.2.4revised/library")

library(htmlwidgets)
library(devtools)

# need to be something in the package
placeholder <- function(x, y) x+y

# generate package
package.skeleton(name = "mywidget", list = c("placeholder"),
                 environment = .GlobalEnv,
                 path = ".", force = FALSE,
                 code_files = character())


# package dir
path <- "C:/Users/kaspe/Desktop/R/practise/htmlWidgets/mywidget"


#devtools::create("mywidget")               # create package using devtools
setwd(path)                          # navigate to package dir
htmlwidgets::scaffoldWidget("mywidget")    # create widget scaffolding
devtools::install()
When I am running the command:
> htmlwidgets::scaffoldWidget("mywidget") # create widget scaffolding
```

It produces the following error:

```
Created boilerplate for widget constructor R/mywidget.R
Error in editor(file = file, title = title) : 
  argument "name" is missing, with no default
```

Same base R and R-studio on both machines.

Does anyone have a clue about what might be wrong here?

Best
Kasper

Comment: What about `htmlwidgets::scaffoldWidget("mywidget", edit = FALSE)`? I don't know anything about windows, but perhaps some analogue of the `$EDITOR` system variable hasn't been properly set.

Comment: RStudio is just a mask around R and should not have any effect on the result.

Comment: @Chris: edit = FALSE worked. Post it as an answer and I will approve it. Thanks guys!

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked. Perhaps as a way to possibly fix it, try running `edit()` and see is there is an error message that shows up. That might give you more information about what exactly is screwy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `htmlwidgets::scaffoldWidget("mywidget", edit = FALSE)`? I don't know anything about windows, but perhaps some analogue of the `$EDITOR` system variable hasn't been properly set.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for some reason!